# Seeing remote mouse through VNC

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, mouse, vnc

I partially understand VNC in that I know, by default, you can only see when desktop itself and the client's mouse is shown. But, I was wondering if there is a different technology out there that allows a remote mouse to be seen or if I can hack together something else in order for that remote mouse to be seen.

I have a Mac Mini that I control with an iPad, but I'm also willing to use a Linux laptop as a client.

Comment: Some VNC servers allow you see the remote cursor.  It's up to the server though to composite that cursor into its screen updates.

Comment: @Brad Do you have examples of VNC Servers that have that functionality?

Comment: I think UltraVNC Server has that option, but I don't have a copy of it handy to check.  It's been awhile since I've used it.

Comment: Same question on different sites: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176127) [2](https://superuser.com/q/811058) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34282363) [4](https://serverfault.com/q/454093)

Answer (score 0):

That would depend entirely on the VPN client being utilized. Typically, the mouse pointer's graphical position is only updated when a "click" event is sent by the client, because graphical updates in most VNC clients are not being "live streamed."

There are other remote desktop clients that will allow you the functionality of "streaming" graphical updates such as Splashtop, or the built-in desktop sharing of Microsoft Lync.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the client if you want to see the **remote** cursor.  Some VNC servers have settings to add the cursor into the data to be drawn to the screen.